# How to display <p> in same line with image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[**DEMO LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/2AFGK/1/)

I want to have `<p>` text displayed in line with the image so everything will look centered and in-line correctly.

Also when screen is shorter and text takes 2+lines (responsive), I'd like this to remain the same as well so the text doesn't jumo below the image.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `<p>` with `<span>`. Then do:

```
.tip span {
    margin-left:10px; 
} 
img {
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Notice that you don't need `display: inline-block` on your span.

Answer (score 1):

### [DEMO REVISED](http://jsfiddle.net/2AFGK/3/)

changed

```
.tip p {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

and added:

```
.tip img {
    float:left;
}
```

`inline-block` to `inline` so that it acts in line within the parent div. `float:left;` to keep the image on the left side of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...This code below works!

```
<img src="" alt="" style="width:32px;height:32px;float:left;">
<p style="margin:0px;height:32px;max-idth:100%;float:left;overflow:auto;">TEST</p>
```

change the 32px to one size that suits you
the style float:left; does the thing you want here